# копирование ячеек с умовой VBA

Tags: vba

у меня есть колонка (А1) там есть н-ное количиство значений к примеру(DAВ-EРA2 (prg) РIT) нужно чтоби ячейки в которих есть чтото записаное в скобках именно(prg) копировалось в следущий столбец но токо информация в скобках (В2) ново созданий.

Comment: Понял так: есть данные в столбце *А*. Если в ячейке есть фрагмент в скобках, копируем этот фрагмент  в столбец *В*... Копировать в ту же строку или формировать список без пустых ячеек? ======  *но токо информация в скобках (В2) ново созданий* - это загадка... *В2* - ячейка или это замена для *(prg)*? Покажите пример исходных данных и результата

Comment: да например есть если в скобках било на 13 позиции в столбце А то надо скопировать на 13 позицию в столбец В. там где нету инфи то просто пропускаем .

Comment: Из первого комментария: *Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос собственными попытками справиться с заданием*  Из второго комментария: *Покажите пример исходных данных и результата*

Comment: могу ли я вставить часть таблици ? @vikttur